# Are there refrigerators with a remote compressor?

Tags: refrigerator

Kind of a crazy question, but is it possible to get a refrigerator with a remote compressor?

I have an "open" style ground floor and a person can hear the whine of the refrigerator's compressor in the dining room and living room.

Ideally I would like to re-situate the refrigerator compressor in the basement (directly below) and put some sound proofing around it to silence it, then run the refrigerant lines through the floor to the refrigerator. Is it possible to get a setup like this?

Comment: They actually (sort of) exist for boats/motorhomes, but they're tiny and 12V - and the pipe is pre-sealed and probably too short for what you'd want

Answer (score 4):

Commercial refrigeration units are available which place the compressor in a remote location. There's a good summary of the pros and cons of such a setup at [Katom Restaurant Supply](https://www.katom.com/cat/commercial-refrigeration/the-pros-and-cons-of-self-contained-remote-refrigeration-katom.html) which is rather comprehensive.

One thing to consider is that a typical home air conditioner is about the equivalent of a refrigerator with a remote compressor.

A post two years ago on [Houzz](https://www.houzz.com/discussions/4814865/removing-fridge-compressor-and-installing-in-basement) website has about 20 comments with nothing conclusive with respect to residential systems, but the expected reference of commercial/restaurant sources.

I'd expect that you'd have to pay the premium for a commercial unit.

Comment: They're called *chillers* at that point and depending on the size you need a class 3 license to work on them. So yeah, no.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a residential unit with a remote compressor/ condensing unit.

You could convert a standard refrig into a split unit similar to a regular household AC unit. You'd have to remove the refrigerant, disconnect the compressor, fan and condensing coils from underneath the refrig and install them in the basement. Then reconnect the tubing and electrical and reinstall the refrigerant (would need a pro to remove and reinstall).

Obviously, this would be a  real challenge for a DIY but it could be done if you really wanted a conversation piece.

Comment: If you can find a friendly hvac tech it can be done - had a demo fridge system made to show how hvac works and the tech found it fun, so it will cost though.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time (early 1900's) refrigerators were built-in cabinetry with insulation and refrigeration, and the compressor was often located in the basement just as you'd like.

I don't think there is an regular household appliance-type refrigerator built this way, but there are commercial refrigerators made with the compressor separate, and built-ins are still made for the commercial and high-end residential market.

[image: built in refrigerator]

If you were going to modify a regular household refrigerator, it would be a bit of a project and you'd probably have trouble getting hold of the refrigerant without a license.  It would also be a challenge fixing the refrigerator in place so you don't tear off the refrigeration lines when you move it.